# Resolution of jpg file

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg, bitmapfactory

I have a class where in constructor I get a file. This file is jpeg. How I can get resolution this jpeg file in this class? 
This is some code from constructor:

```
public static Bitmap bitmapSizer(File file) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
        options.inDither = true;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inSampleSize=8;         
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move a few lines of code.
First, get the `Options` object up:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inDither = true;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inSampleSize=8;         
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

Note the `options.inJustDecodeBounds =`**true**
This will only read jpg's header, not the whole image.
Next, decode your file:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

After decoding you'll get the results in:

```
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```